# Custom command for switching background image

Tags: macros, backgrounds

I use the wallpaper package to put a PDF document in the background of my document.

I want the user to be able to select in the preamble which PDF should be use as background image like this:

```
\output{print} or \output{screen}
```

I thought I can write the command like this:

```
\newcommand{\output}[1]{
  \ifstrequal{#1}{print}{
     \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{backgroundPrint.pdf}
   }{
      \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{background.pdf}
   }
}
```

But this does not work. I have found out that this, however, works:

```
\newcommand{\print}{
   \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{backgroundPrint.pdf}
}
\newcommand{\screen}{
    \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{background.pdf}
}
```

which works nicely, but I really want to know what the problem is with my initial approach.

I have also tried the approach described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93908/macro-for-declaring-variables-in-class-files) but without success.

I'm not much into LaTeX programming so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. What “does not work”? What happens? Error messages? Different output than expected? Have you tried another macro name instead of `\output` which may already be defined (though this would come up in an error message, as well)?

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\output` is already defined (it is a TeX primitive, → [Why can't I use \newfloat more than once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2749/16595)) as one can see in the log:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \output already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

You will need to use a different macro name, say `\Output`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper,graphicx,etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\Output}[1]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{print}{%
     \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{example-image-A.pdf}% example-image-? is from the mwe package
  }{%
     \ULCornerWallPaper{1}{example-image-B.pdf}%
  }%
}
\Output{print}
\begin{document}
Nothing to see here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I missed the info in the log.